# Derive necessary conditions to find an approximation to A: $min_{u\in R^{m}} ||A - uv^{T}||_{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Derive and establish necessary conditions for the following statement.

Given an m-by-n real matrix $A$ and unit vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, find $u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, so that the rank-1 matrix $uv^{T}$ is a best approximation to $A$: $min_{u\in R^{m}} ||A - uv^{T}||_{F}$.

We can assume that m, n, rank(A) are greater than two, and that there exists a best approximation, $u_{0}v^{T}$.

I'm not sure where to take this question, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(u)||A-uv^T||^2=tr(AA^T-2uv^TA^T+uu^T)$. Its derivative is

$Df_u:h\in\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow tr(-2hv^TA^T+2hu^T)$.

If $f$ admits a minimum in $u$, then, for every $h$, $tr(-hv^TA^T+hu^T)=0$, that implies $-v^TA^T+u^T=0$, 
or $u=Av$.

Comment: So, in this instance, the necessary condition on the best approximation is that f admits a minimum. In that case, it is sufficient to determine the best approximation $u_{0} = Av$? Or is my understanding of this solution incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the minimum is obtained for $u_0=Av.$